# Conemu suppresses launch of an OpenGL application

Tags: conemu

Getting tired of the terrible `cmd` window, I found `ConEmu` which turned out to be a great replacement... except it suppresses the creation of the `OpenGL` window when I double-click launch the `exe` (I have `ConEmu` take over the normal `cmd` window completely).

If I launch the `exe` by going to the folder through `ConEmu` and typing out the name `testOpenGL.exe` then the application window launches properly.

It would be great if anyone has come across a similar issue and knows the solution.

> Link to file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/meif3dgq4cxq5ct/tlocInputCallbacks.7z?dl=0
>
> The window itself is empty because nothing is drawn (wanted to avoid sharing assets), but it *shows up*. That is, without `ConEmu` the console shows up as well as the window with an `OpenGL` context. Double clicking and letting `ConEmu` handle the console output *does not* spawn the window. Running the app manually through `ConEmu` by using the command prompt running the `exe` fixes the issue.

Comment: Your OpenGL is console application??

Comment: yes, it is so that I can print to console. Otherwise I have to go through some hoops just to get the console up and running.

Comment: And where is that app?

Comment: @Maximus: not sure what you mean by 'where'? It is built by `VS` and is put in a `bin` folder. I then run the application by double clicking the `exe`. In the case of `ConEmu` (which I have now uninstalled unfortunately) the console shows all the log messages but the window (which has the `OpenGL` context`) is not launched.